# Send greeting to a newly connected client

Tags: java, netty

I'm writing a tcp server with netty and want to send some greetings to all newly  connected clients. As of now I'm intending to do that with `ChannelInitializer`

```
ServerBootstrap b;
//...
b.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
 .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>()) {
     public void init(SocketChannel ch){
         ch.pipeline(). //...
         ch.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Hi there!", CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
     }
  }
```

Since everything in netty is asynchronous I'm not sure if this is the right way to send greeting on connection succeeded. Can someone suggest a recommended way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this via a `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` once the `channelActive` callback is executed.

Something like:

`public class GreetingHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ch.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Hi there!", CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }
}`